# Copy the 9-patch from one image to another ones

Tags: android-studio, nine-patch

Is it possible to copy the 9-patch from one image to another?. I have 5 images (25 total) for every screen dpi, and all of them uses the same 9-patch. Actually I have to apply the same 9-patch manually to every one of them, so I was wondering if I can copy from one to another.

Comment: Have you found the solution ?